# SQL - Get boolean values for each matching field

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help with SQL request.

I have 3 tables:

Table **User**

```
id  name
1   Jon
2   Jack
3   Bill
```

Table **Type**

```
id  name
1   View
2   Edit
3   Delete
```

Table **Right**

```
id  user  type
1   1     1
2   1     2
3   1     3
4   2     1
5   3     1
```

So table **Right** contains linked pairs of user-type. I need a request which gets user name, and a boolean (BIT) value for each enrty in table **Type**, which exists in **Right** table for this user. Something like this for my example tables:

```
Username  View  Edit  Delete
Jon       1     1     1
Jack      1     0     0 
Bill      1     0     0
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Is this SQL Server or MySQL? They are completely different products.

Comment: it's MySQL, I removed wrong tag, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

untested:

```
select name,
       coalesce(select 1 from `right` where `type` = 1 and right.user = user.id, 0) as `View`,
       coalesce(select 1 from `right` where `type` = 2 and right.user = user.id, 0) as `Edit`,
       coalesce(select 1 from `right` where `type` = 3 and right.user = user.id, 0) as `Delete`
from User
```

Alternatively:

```
select name, coalesce(RVIEW.R, 0) as `View`, coalesce(REDIT.R, 0) as `Edit`, coalesce(RDEL.R, 0) as `Delete`
from User
left join (select 1 R from `right` where `type` = 1) RVIEW on (right.user = user.id)
left join (select 1 R from `right` where `type` = 2) REDIT on (right.user = user.id)
left join (select 1 R from `right` where `type` = 3) RDEL on (right.user = user.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are using reserved words as table names.

If you want to learn more about naming conventions for table names, have a look at the links in an earlier question on Stack Overflow  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290609/what-is-the-best-practice-in-naming-your-user-table)

Example below shows yet another way of getting the data you want (with other names for the tables):

```
select  person.name as Username
,       max( if( person_right.type_id = 1, 1, 0 ) ) as `View`
,       max( if( person_right.type_id = 2, 1, 0 ) ) as `Edit`
,       max( if( person_right.type_id = 3, 1, 0 ) ) as `Delete`

from person

left outer join person_right
on person_right.user_id = person.id

group by person.name
order by person.id
```

Another thing that might be worth looking at is the datamodel, 
because Rights are normally quite "fixed".

If anyone accidentally changes one of the names in the Type table, you might have a serious security issue.

What you can do is change the person_right table to look like this

```
windowid  user_id  view_access  edit_access  delete_access
1         1        1            1            1
1         2        1            0            0
1         3        1            0            0
```

where the primary key would be window_id+user_id allowing you to setup different rights per user in a particular window/part of your application.

Hope this helps.