# table does not exist after succesfull creation

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1146

I used MySQL through command line in order to create a database named `javafxsample`. The code is as folls:

```
create database javafxsample;
use javafxsample;

create table if not exists user(
    id int(11) not null auto_increment,
    username varchar(255) not null unique,
    last_name varchar(255) not null,
    first_name varchar(255) not null,
    password varchar(255) not null,
    created_at datetime not null default current_timestamp,
    primary key(id)
);
```

The database `javafxsample` is created successfully in MySQL command line. (I know this because I can see it using `SHOW DATABASES;`.) However, when I try to see it using `DESCRIBE javafxsample;`, I got this error message:

> ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'javafxsample.javafxsample' doesn't exist.

I do not know how to solve this issue, nor why I can not see the table `javafxsample`. I am using MySQL server version 5.7.24. Any help or suggestion(s) in order to get this table work is really appreciated.

Comment: @Simonare has mentioned the resolution to the error. You also need to consider giving a valid and better name to your table. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290609/what-is-the-best-practice-in-naming-your-user-table

Answer (score 3):

`javafxsample` is your database. you cannot use describe on database.

Try `describe user` instead

Answer (score 1):

The error "`ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'javafxsample.javafxsample' doesn't exist`" says table "`javafxsample`" does not exists in "`javafxsample`" database.

You create database "`javafxsample`" and table "`user`".

So try describing your user table like `DESCRIBE user`

Comment: i already used "DESCRIBE user" and finally i get the information of my table javafxsample without no creating a new table named "user", it can see the elements inside table, thank you very much!!!

Comment: thank you very much for your help, thank you, i already solved this problem