# Which are the best practices to set name in a database?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I need how set name to tables and fields, example:

TABLENAME , TABLENAME_ID , OR TableName, TableNameID

tablename , tablename_userID , or tablename, userID

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you are trying to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702728/relational-table-naming-convention

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [ISO-11179 Naming Conventions](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/iso-11179-naming-conventions)

You want

**11179-5**
Part 5: Naming and Identification Principles, provides guidance for the identification of administered items. Identification is a broad term for designating, or identifying, a particular data item. Identification can be accomplished in various ways, depending upon the use of the identifier. Identification includes the assignment of numerical identifiers that have no inherent meanings to humans; icons (graphic symbols to which meaning has been assigned); and names with embedded meaning, usually for human understanding, that are associated with the data item’s definition and value domain.

Answer (score 1):

SQLMenace provided the long answer which has a lot of good information.

Short answer: TableName

Although I am sure you will get arguments from many on this site since table_name is all over the place here.

Take a look at this post:  [Relational table naming convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702728/relational-table-naming-convention/4703155#4703155)