# How to display item as 'in transit' instead of to specific location id (foreign key)?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I have following requirements for item management.

1. Item can be moved from location 'A' to 'B'. And later on it can also be moved from 'B' to 'C' location.
2. History should be maintained for each item to display it location wise items for specific period, can be display item wise history.
3. Also I need to display items 'in transit' on particular date.

Given below is the database design:

```
item_master
-----------
- ItemId
- Item name 
- etc...

item_location_history
------------------
- ItemId
- LocationId (foreign key of location_master)
- Date
```

While item is being transported I want to insert data in following way:
1. At the time of transport I want to enter item to be moved from location 'A' to 'In Transit' on particular date. As there is possibilities that item remains in 'in transit' state for several days.
2. At the time of receive at location 'B' I want to insert item to be moved from 'In Transit' to location 'B' on particular date and so on.

This way I will have track of both 'In Transit' state and item location.

What is the best way to achieve this? What changes I need to apply to the above schema? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Initial Response

> *What is the best way to achieve this?*

This is a simple and common Data Modelling Problem, and the answer (at least in the Relational Database context) is simple.  I would say, every database has at least a few of these.  Unfortunately, because the authors who write books about the *Relational Model*, are in fact completely ignorant of it, they do not write about this sort of simple straight-forward issue, or the simple solution.

What you are looking for is an `OR` gate.  In this instance, because the `Item` is in a `Location XOR` it is `InTransit,` you need an `XOR` gate.

In Relational terms, this is a **Basetype::Subtype structure**.  If it is implemented properly, it provides full integrity, and eliminates Nulls.

As far as I know, it is the **only** Relational method.  Beware, the methods provided by famous writers are non-relational, monstrous, massively inefficient, and they don't work.

###Record ID

But first ... I would not be serving you if I didn't mention that your files have no integrity right now, you have a Record Filing System. This is probably not your fault, in that the famous writers know only pre-1970's Record Filing Systems, so that is all that they can teach, but the problem is, they badge it "relational", and that is untrue.  They also have various myths about the *RM*, such as *it doesn't support hierarchies*, etc.

- By starting with an `ID` stamped on every table, the data modelling process is crippled
- You have no Row Uniqueness, as is required for RDBS.
- an `ID` is not a Key.
- If you do not understand that, please read [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29726132/484814).

I have partially corrected those errors:

- In `Item`, I have given a more useful PK.  I have never heard any user discuss an `Item RecordId`, they always uses `Codes.`
- Often those codes are made up of components, if so, you need to record those components in separate columns (otherwise you break 1NF).
- `Item` needs an Alternate Key on `Name,` otherwise you will allow duplicate Names.
- In `Location,` I have proposed a Key, which identifies an unique physical location.  Please modify to suit.
- If `Location` has a `Name,` that needs to be an AK.
- I have not given you the Predicates.  These are very important, for many reasons.  The main reason here, is that it will prove the insanity of Record IDs.  If you want them, please ask.
- If you would like more information on Predicates, visit [**this Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29711063/484814), scroll down (way down!) to **Predicate**, and read that section.  Also check the ERD for them.

###Solution

> *What changes [do] I need to apply to the above schema?*

Try this:

- **Item History Data Model**
  (Obsolete, refer below for the updated mode, in the context of the progression)
- If you are not used to the Notation, please be advised that every little tick, notch, and mark, the solid vs dashed lines, the square vs round corners, means something very specific.  Refer to the [**IDEF1X Notation**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Introduction.pdf) for a full explanation, or [**Model Anatomy**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Model%20Anatomy.pdf).
- If you have not encountered Subtypes implemented properly before, please read this [**Subtype Overview**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Article/Database/Relational%20Model/Subtype.pdf)
- That is a self-contained document, with links to code examples
- There is also an SO discussion re [**How to implement referential integrity in subtypes**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896831/how-to-implement-referential-integrity-in-subtypes).
- When contemplating a Subtype cluster, consider each Basetype::Subtype pair as a single unit, do not perceive them as two fragments, or two halves.  Each pair in one fact.
- `ItemHistory` is an event (a fact) in the history of an `Item.`
- Each `ItemHistory` fact is either a `Location` fact `XOR` an `InTransit` fact.
- Each of those facts has different attributes.
- Notice that the model represents the simple, honest, truth about the real world that you are engaging.  In addition to the integrity, etc, as discussed above, the result is simple straight-forward code: every other "solution" makes the code complex, in order to handle exception cases.  And some "solutions" are more horrendous than others.
- Dr E F Codd gave this to us in 1970.  It was implemented it as a modelling method in 1984, named IDEF1X.  That became the standard for Relational Databases in 1993. I have used it exclusively since 1987.
- But the authors who write books, allegedly on the *Relational Model*, have **no knowledge whatsoever, about any of these items**.  They know only pre-1970's ISAM Record Filing Systems.  They do not even know *that* they do not have the Integrity, Power, or Speed of Relational Databases, let alone *why* they don't have it.
- Date, Darwen, Fagin, Zaniolo, Ambler, Fowler, Kimball, are all promoting an incorrect view of the RM.

## Response to Comments

> *1) ItemHistory, contains Discriminator column 'InTransit'.*

Correct.  And all the connotations that got with that: it is a control element; its values better be constrained; etc.

> *Shall it be enum with the value Y / N?*

First, understand that the value-stored has meaning.  That meaning can be expressed any way you like.  In English it means `{Location|InTransit}.`

For the storage, I know it is the values for the proposition `InTransit` are `{True|False},` ...

In SQL (if you want the real article, which is portable), I intended it as a `BIT` or `BOOLEAN.`  Think about what you want to show up in the reports.  In this case it is a control element, so it won't be present in the user reports.  There I would stick to `InTransit={0|1}.`

But if you prefer `{Y|N},` that is fine.  Just keep that consistent across the database (do not use `{0|1}` in one place and `{Y|N}` in another).

For values that *do* show up in reports, or columns such as EventType, I would use `{InTransit|Location}.`

In SQL, for implementation, if it `BOOLEAN`, the domain (range-of-values) is already constrained. nothing further is required.

If the column were other `BOOLEAN`,` you have two choices:

1. `CHECK`Constraint

   ```
       CHECK @InTransit IN ( "Y", "N" )
   ```
2. Reference or Lookup Table

Implement a table that contains only the valid domain.  The requirement is a single column, the Code itself.  And you can add a column for short Descriptor that shows up in reports.  `CHAR(12)`works nicely for me.

---

**`ENUM`**

There is no `ENUM` in SQL.  Some of the non-SQL databases have it.  Basically it implements option [2] above, with a Lookup table, under the covers.  It doesn't realise that the rows are unique, and so it **Enumerates** the rows, hence the name, but it adds a column for the number, which is of course an `ID` replete with `AUTOINCREMENT,` so MySQL falls into the category of *Stupid Thing to Do* as described in [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29726132/484814) (scroll down to the **Lookup Table** section).

So no, do not use `ENUM` unless you wish to be glued at the hip to a home-grown, stupid, non-SQL platform, and suffer a rewrite when the database is ported to a real SQL platform.  The platform might be stupid, but that is not a good reason to go down the same path.  Even if MySQL is all you have, use one of the two SQL facilities given above, do not use `ENUM.`

---

> *2) Why is'ItemHistoryTransit' needed as 'Date' column*

(`DATETIME,`not `DATE,` but I don't think that matters.)

> *[It] is there in ItemHistory?*

The standard method of constraining (everything in the database is constrained) the nature of teh Basetype::Subtype relationship is, to implement the exact same PK of the Basetype in the Subtype.  The Basetype PK is`(ItemCode, DateTime).`

> *[Why] will only Discriminator not work?*

It is wrong, because it doesn't follow the standard requirement, and thus allows weird and wonderful values. I can't think of an instance where that could be justified, even if a replacement constraint was provided.

Second, there can well be more than two occs of `ItemEvents`that are `InTransit`per ItemCode,`which that does not allow.

Third, it does not match the Basetype PK value.

#### Solution

- Actually, a better name for the table would be `ItemEvent.`  Labels are keys to understanding.
- I have given the Predicates, please review carefully.
- Data model updated.
- [**Item Event Data Model**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Student%20Resolutions/Mohit%20Mehta%20DM.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a boolean field for in_transit to item_location_history so when it is getting moved from Location A to Location B, you set the LocationId to Location B (so you know where it is going) but then when it actually arrives you log another row with LocationId as LocationB but with in_transit as false. That way you know when it arrived also.

If you don't need to know where it is headed when it is "in transit" then you could just add "In Transit" as a location and keep your schema the same. In the past with an inventory applicaiton, I went as far as making each truck a location so that we knew what specific truck the item was in.

Comment: I already considered this option, also I considered to insert LocationId null at the time of transit and insert another row at the time of receiving with new LocationId. And I'm confused with these two options.

Comment: There is no general right or wrong answer, but only what is right or wrong for your specific application. You have to think along the terms of what data are you going to need and making sure you can pull it efficiently with your data structure. I would assume at some point you're going to want to know what is on the way to a given location... not just that it is in transit to some unknown location... which is why I suggested the additional field.

Answer (score 0):

One of the techniques I've adopted over the years is to normalize transitional attributes (qty, status, location, etc.) from the entity table. If you also want to track the history, just version (versionize?) the subsequent status table.

```
create table ItemLocation(
    ItemID     int,
    Effective  date,
    LocationID int,
    Remarks    varchar( 256 ),
    constraint PK_ItemLocation primary key( ItemID, Effective ),
    constraint FK_ItemLocation_Item foreign key( ItemID )
        references Items( ID ),
    constraint FK_ItemLocation_Location foreign key( LocationID )
        references Locations( ID )
);
```

There are several good design options, I've shown the simplest, where "In transit" is implied. Consider the following data:

```
ItemID  Effective  LocationID   Remarks
======  =========  ==========   ===============================
  1001  2015-04-01         15   In location 15
  1001  2015-04-02       NULL   In Transit [to location xx]
  1001  2015-04-05         17   In location 17
```

Item 1001 appears in the database when it arrives at location 15, where it spends one whole day. The next day it is removed and shipped. Three days later it arrives at location 17 where it is remains to this day.

Implied meanings are generally frowned upon and are indeed easy to overdo. If desired, you can add an actual status field to contain "In location" and "In Transit" values. You may well consider such a course if you think there could be other status values added later (QA Testing, Receiving, On Hold, etc.). But for just two possible values, In Location or In Transit, implied meaning works.

At any rate, you know the current whereabouts of any item by fetching the LocationID with the latest Effective date. You also have a history of where the item is at any date -- and both can be had with the same query.

```
declare AsOf date = sysdate;

select  i.*, il.Effective, IfNull( l.LocationName, 'In Transit' ) as Location
from    Items i
join    ItemLocation il
    on  il.ItemID = i.ID
    and il.Effective =(
        select  Max( Effective )
        from    ItemLocation
        where   ItemID = il.ItemID
            and Effective <= AsOf )
left join Locations  l
    on  l.ID = il.LocationID;
```

Set the AsOf value to "today" to get the most recent location or set it to any date to see the location *as of* that date. Since the current location will be far and away the most common query, define a view that generates just the current location and use that in the join.

```
join    CurrentItemLocation cil
    on  cil.ItemID = i.ID
left join Locations  l
    on  l.ID = cil.LocationID;
```