# The problem with Mongodb Atlas naming convention

Tags: mongodb, collections, naming-conventions, rules, mongodb-atlas

I am having a problem with the **naming convention of MongoDB**.
I am unable to access MongoDB collection data when

1. naming the collection with camelCase.
2. collection name ends with "ss". for eg collection name "abyss".
   Does MongoDB follow the same rule as relational Databases?

Comment: Hi, how are you trying to access does collections? Could you be more specific about "relational Databases rule"?

Comment: Please find here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702728/relational-table-naming-convention#:~:text=The%20format%20is%20the%20table,underscore%2C%20and%20finally%20the%20suffix.&text=Foreign%20Keys%20(the%20constraint%2C%20not%20the%20column).