# Am I overcomplicating this database design for approvals

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I'm building an approval workflow as part of a web application I am developing to assist our managers in new hire planning which we call "Class Requests" for our business units which are called "Districts".

I have no formal experience in database or web design, but when I was building out the tables for the approval process I came up with 6 different tables which seemed excessive, and I'm worried I am overcomplicating things.

First the `classrequest` table (not part of the approval process tables) columns:

- districtid
- classsize
- TheWeekEndingDate
- approvalstatusid (part of approval process)
- newrequestedclasssize (null by default, int >0 if the class size is requested to change)
- cancellationrequested (0 by default, 1 if the class is requested to be cancelled)
- createdby
- createdon
- modifiedby
- modifiedon

New class request: when a new row is created, an approval process is initiated by adding rows to these two tables:

**(1)** `Approvals` table columns:

- id
- classrequestid
- **approvaltypeid**
- **approvalstatusid**
- cancelapproval (bit, default to 0)

**(2)** `ApprovalDetails` Table columns

- id
- approvalid
- **approverid**
- **approvalstatusid**

**How are bolded values generated on insert?**

How are these values generated: approvaltypeid, approvalstatusid, approverid?

**approvaltypeid** is from approvaltypes table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | New Request |
| 2 | Change Class Size |
| 3 | Cancel Class |

When a new row is created, id 1 is used. When a class size change is requested, id 2, and when the class is requested to be cancelled, id 3.

**approvalstatusid** is from approval statuses table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Pending |
| 2 | Approved |
| 3 | Declined |
| 4 | Approval Cancelled |

Default is 1

**approverid** is from approverdistrictmapping table:

- id
- districtid
- approvaltypeid
- approverid (List of approvers is the approvers table)
- deleted (defaults to 0, 1 means ignore this row)

So when an approval is entered into the approvals table, new rows get inserted into the approvaldetails table for each approver for that districtid and approvaltypeid.

**Summary**

So six total tables: approvals, approvaldetails, approvalstatuses, approvaltypes, approverdistrictmapping, and approvers.

Three approval functions are allowed for:

1. A new request (inserted row into class request table)
2. A class size change request, which involves changing the newrequestedclasssize variable from null to >0
3. Cancelling an existing class request, which changes the cancellationrequested flag from 0 to 1.

Additionally, approvals themselves can be cancelled. If a user wants to change a class size from 10 to 5, for example, and then changes their mind, they can cancel approval process (as long as it is still in progress) and keep the class at 10.

All approvers in the approvaldetails table must approve for the approvalstatus table to update to approved, and if any decline the approval status table will update to declined.

Did I overcomplicate this? Is there room for simplification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relational data modeling is all about defining a **language** (in a very formal sense) to describe **facts** by combining elementary facts with precise rules. Stop thinking in terms of tables (the number of which is irrelevant—you will have as many tables as necessary to model the relevant facts) and start thinking in terms of which kinds of facts you need. The following is a tentative, informal, and incomplete list based on my understanding of your requirements. I use capital initials for the identified entities and attributes in the model.

- Your organization is divided into “Districts”, each identified by a DistrictNo (I intentionally avoid using “id” to make it clear that the identifier is not made up and without semantics—that is, it is not a surrogate—but it refers to the way your organization distinguishes between districts—how do people refer to a district in a request?).
- Each District may receive many Requests. You didn't say how a Request is to be identified, so I will assume that each District assigns a RequestNo to its own Requests.
- Each Request may be of one of three different types: for a new Class, for updating a Class, for cancelling a Class. Again, you did not identify “classes” as part of your modeling attempt, but they must be obviously modeled (see below). Let's say that each class is assigned a unique ClassNo (again, something your organization uses to identify the various classes).
- A New Class Request must specify the Class Size and the EndDate of the class.
- A Change Size Request must specify the new size for the Class—and *which Class should be updated*.
- A Cancel Class Request must specify *which Class should be cancelled*.
- Note that each of New Class Request, Change Size Request, and Cancel Class Request is a Request (*exclusive subtyping*—search for that term).
- For each received Request—no matter the type—the competent District assigns a certain number of Approvers that must evaluate the Request.
- Each Approver provides a Decision whether to approve an assigned Request or not.
- The RequestStatus of a Request is Pending as long as there is an Approver who has not expressed an evaluation; it becomes Declined if any Approver refuses to approve the Request; it becomes Approved as soon as all Approvers have accepted the Request.
- As long as a RequestStatus is not Approved or Declined, it is always possible to set the RequestStatus to Cancelled, which means that the request is no longer valid.
- As soon as the RequestStatus for a New Class Request becomes Approved, a new Class can be created, with the requested ClassSize and EndDate.
- As soon as the RequestStatus for a Change Size Request becomes Approved, the size of the corresponding Class can be updated as requested.
- As soon as the RequestStatus for a Cancel Class Request becomes Approved, a Class can be Cancelled.
- If a Request is Pending, Declined or Cancelled, the corresponding action cannot be taken, of course.

Note that some of the statements above are about state transitions, rather than states. I am not entering into the details of how to force correct transitions, i.e., modeling behaviour. Some things can be modelled declaratively; others are part of the application logic.

This is a possible rendition of the requirements above in IDEF1X:

[Draft IDEF1X Model for Requests and Approvals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTrQL.png)

The independent entities in light blue are considered pre-populated and are seldom updated, if ever. You start by inserting Districts, e.g.:

```
insert into District(DistrictNo, Name) value (100, 'Sales');
```

Yellow and pink tables are where most transactions take place. A new request is first inserted in Pending state:

```
insert into Request(DistrictNo, RequestNo, RequestType, RequestStatus, …)
values (100, 1, 'New', 'Pending', …);

insert into NewClassRequest(DistrictNo, RequestNo, ClassSize, EndDate)
values (100, 1, 10, '2023-12-12');
```

Note that the two insertions above must always happen atomically.

Then, approvers are assigned to the request:

```
insert into RequestApprover(DistrictNo, RequestNo, Approver)
values (100, 1, 'Ada'), (100, 1, 'Joe');
```

When an approver has taken a decision, that is recorded in RequestDecision:

```
insert into RequestDecision(DistrictNo, RequestNo, Approver, Approved)
values (100, 1, 'Ada', 'yes');
```

After a request is approved by all assigned approvers, its state is updated and a new class is created:

```
update Request set RequestStatus = 'Approved'
 where DistrictNo = 100 and RequestNo = 1;

insert into Class(DistrictNo, ClassNo, RequestNo, ClassSize, EndDate)
values (100, 1000, 1, 10, '2023-12-12');
```

Note that for each class you keep track of the originating request.

The other types of requests are dealt with similarly. For example, to create a change size request:

```
insert into Request(DistrictNo, RequestNo, RequestType, RequestStatus, …)
values (100, 2, 'Update', 'Pending', …);

insert into ChangeSizeRequest(DistrictNo, RequestNo, NewClassSize, ClassNo)
values (100, 2, 18, 1000);
```

Then you insert the approvers, wait for their decisions, update the request's status and, if the request has been approved, you update Class.

Note that the proposed model is far from being perfect and can certainly be improved in many ways (for example, you probably want at most one pending request at a time for the same class). But I hope it will help you guide your towards a satisfactory solution for your problem.

---

I strongly suggest that you acquire a minimum of expertise in data modeling. IDEF1X is the best (Relational) data modeling technique I know of: there are many posts on SO about it, with links to good resources. You may also take a look at appendix A2–A3 of [FIPS PUB 184](https://archive.org/details/federalinformati184nati/), which is an old but still good introduction.

Comment: I haven't said anything about naming conventions, but see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702728/relational-table-naming-convention/4703155#4703155).

Comment: Wow this is super helpful, thank you so much. One mistake I think I made in my design and you carried over is the Class table has a RequestNo FK. Since Request:Class is many:one, should that be reversed? Should we drop the RequestNo FK from the Class table and add a ClassNo FK to the Request table? That would imply that either the application presenting the data to the user, or the view that presents the data to the application, would need the logic to look among the Request, Approver, and Decision tables to come up with some sort of overall request status. 
I will read this many more times.

Comment: No class exists until a request to create one is approved: there cannot be a FK from Request to Class. And the relationship between NewClassRequest and Class is one-to-one (either one class is created as requested, or it isn't). The one-to-many relationship is between Class and the other types of requests: and that's reflected in the model (it's slightly more complicated than that: there may be many cancel requests for one class, but at most one may be approved). What's missing is establishing a *hierarchy* of Requests, so that there is at most one active request per class at any given moment.

Comment: As I've said, the model is far from perfect. My goal was not to give you the best solution, but to suggest a way of approaching a data modeling task (and there's much more to that) by laying out some simple predicates first (“A District receives many Requests / A Request is sent to one District”), identifying the *keys* next (“A Request is identified by…”) and with the help of a diagrammatic tool supporting organizing those facts into a coherent model.

Re the “overall request status”, what do you mean? The status is an attribute of each Request.

Comment: Ah wait, I see: yes, determining whether the status of a request can or should be changed and how is part of your business logic. Currently, a request gets approved when all approvers are favourable. But, if that changes in the future—perhaps a request can be accepted if the majority of approvers approve—you don't need to change the model.

Comment: More what I meant was a Class can have a finite number of Request Types, and one of the Request Types can have infinite number of Requests. From the perspective of an application user (an operational leader) they should be able to select a district and get a list of Classes with a very clear indication of the status of each class. The information stored in the database might not be the most intuitive to the leader. For example, for a Class with an approved New Request and a pending Change Size request, I need some business logic to display something like "Approved; change request pending"